# System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am getting the error above, I really am stuck at the moment, it is a plain form that I am trying to add a control dynamically when I click a button.
I have highligted in a comment on the code where I am getting the error "pnltxtProductDescription.Controls.Add(txt) ' THIS IS WHERE I AM GETTING THE ERROR"

My ASP Page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Pages/master-pages/main.Master" CodeBehind="quotation-new.aspx.vb" Inherits="iconHub.quotation_new1" %>
```

```
<title>New Quotation | iconHub</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

```
<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
    <!-- MAIN CONTENT WRAPPER -->
    <div id="main-content-wrapper" class="content-wrapper ">

            <div class="main-content">

                        <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <table class="table table-bordered">

                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="col-md-1">#</th>
                                            <th class="col-md-2">Item</th>
                                            <th class="col-md-4">Description</th>
                                            <th class="col-md-2">Unit Cost</th>
                                            <th class="col-md-1">Quantity</th>
                                            <th class="col-md-2">Line Total</th>

                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>

                                </table>
                            </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <!--Left Column-->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtProductDescription" runat="server" id="txtProductDescription">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row">

                                <asp:Panel ID="pnltxtProductDescription" runat="server">
                                </asp:Panel>                                      
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 pull-right" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <asp:Button id="cmdAddLine" CssClass="btn btn-default nextBtn btn-sm pull-right" runat="server" onclick="AddTextBox" Text="Add Line" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Behind Page Code

```
Public Class quotation_new1 Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub AddTextBox(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim index As Integer
    'Description
    index = pnltxtProductDescription.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().ToList().Count + 1
    CreatetxtProductDescription("txtProductDescription" & index)


End Sub

Private Sub CreatetxtProductDescription(id As String)
    Dim txt As New TextBox
    txt.ID = id

    pnltxtProductDescription.Controls.Add(txt) ' THIS IS WHERE I AM GETTING THE ERROR

    Dim lt As New Literal With {
        .Text = "<br />"
    }
    pnltxtProductDescription.Controls.Add(lt)
End Sub




Protected Sub Page_PreInit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
    Dim keys As List(Of String) = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(Function(key) key.Contains("txtProductDescription")).ToList()
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    For Each key As String In keys
        CreatetxtProductDescription("txtProductDescription" & i)
        i += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's failing is because you are calling `CreatetxtProductDescription()` from your `PreInit` event. `PreInit` fires before controls are initialized, including your `Panel` control (See the [ASP.Net Page Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)). Since the `Panel` control hasn't been created yet, it's throwing a `NullException` error when you try to access the `.Controls` property.

To fix your issue, move your code that's in the `PreInit` event to the `Load` event instead.